# Node.JS where to put the response.end()

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, response

I'm developing a simple NODE.JS application. First I create an httpServer using http module. Then I route the request to the requestsHandlers.js page. 'Response' parameter cames from the creation of the httpServer. Process1, process2 and process3 should write an answer to the page. This is the objective of this app, that process1, process2 and process3 write its respective text.

**requestHandlers.js**

```
var process1 = require("./process1");
var process2 = require("./process2");
var process3 = require("./process3");


function iniciar(response) {
  console.log("Manipulador de petición 'iniciar' fue llamado.");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});

  process1.fc1(response);
  process2.fc2(response);
  process3.fc3(response);

  //response.end() //WHERE DO I PLACE IT?
}
```

As you can see, the response parameter is passed to process1.js, which after parsing some data shoud echo some information.

**process1.js**

```
var request = require('request')

function fc1 (response){

  var url = 'http://webpagethatreturnsJSONfile.com/'

  //Download webpage data and parses it
  request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
    var jsonResult = JSON.parse(body);
    response.write("Number:" + jsonResult.number + '');
    //response.end() //WHERE DO I PLACE IT?
  });
}

exports.fc1 = fc1;
```

The point is that I don't know where to put 'response.end()'. Each process takes some time and I want to 'end' when all processes have echo their text.

How could I do it?
I don't know if the code I've attached is enough for helping me.

Comment: check out the topic on "full parallel"   here : http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html

Comment: No problem glad it helped , in future check out design patterns before you implement it could save you a major headache